# load d3 with amd using dojo

Tags: d3.js, dojo

Hi I'm using dojo in amd mode for my main app (html page).  I would like to create a module that references d3 library to create some charts.  I'm having trouble creating this module -- what I've got so far for the module (a javascript file) is this:

```
define(["d3"], function (d3) {
    return {
        setd3ChartData: function () {
            //this function can be called from my main app
             //but d3 isnt linked to the d3 js library
        }
    }
});
```

in my main app I've got a link to the d3 libary in a script tag

How can I get this script link into the module?  I can access d3 library just fine from main app

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 5):

When you want to use D3 with Dojo you probably first want to define the D3 package in your [Dojo config](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/). For example (when using a CDN):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        parseOnLoad: true,
        packages: [{
            name: "d3",
            location: "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.6/"
        }]
    }
</script>
```

Then you can use D3 by using:

```
require([ "d3/d3" ], function(d3) {
    // Do stuff with "d3"
});
```

The reason you have to use `"d3/d3"` and not just `"d3"` is that the part before the `/` indicated the package name, in this case it's **d3** (which we configured using `dojoConfig`).

The second part is the actual file, or in this case **d3.js**.

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jSAH9/) to show a working example of D3 loaded using the AMD loader. In that example I placed the Dojo configuration under the Fiddle options, but the setup is the same.

I also renamed the callback to `d3Lib`, because D3 by defaults creates the `d3` global variable and now you can clearly see it's working with AMD.

---

If you want to use the minified version you can load `"d3/d3.min"`.